# How to manage multiple balances for one account?

Tags: pallet, balances, transfer, lockable-currency

Here is my scenario: One account will maintain 3 balances of Token A, Token B, Token C.
When Alice sends x Token A to Bob, it should deposit to Bob's balance for the same kind of token, means Token A. Similarly for Token C, but Token B is not transferable.

Inside the same about, It is possible to convert Token A into Token C with a conversion rate.
So, how should I implement them?
and What I did so far is?

```rust
#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
    
    use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;
    use frame_support::traits::Currency;
    use frame_support::serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

    #[pallet::pallet]
    pub struct Pallet<T>(_);

    //#[cfg(feature = "std")]
    type TokenABalanceOf<T> = <<T as Config>::Token as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance;
    type TokenBBalanceOf<T> = <<T as Config>::TokenB as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance;
    type TokenCBalanceOf<T> = <<T as Config>::TokenC as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance;


    pub trait TokenAManagement<T:Config> {
        // fn convert_to_TokenC(from: T::&AccountId, amount: TokenBalanceOf<T>) -> DispatchResult;
        fn withdraw(owner: T::AccountId, amount: TokenBalanceOf<T>) -> DispatchResult;
        // fn transfer(from: &T::AccountId, to: &AccountId, value: TokenBalanceOf<T>) -> DispatchResult;
        fn deposit(owner: T::AccountId, amount: u32) -> DispatchResult;
    }

    pub trait TokenBManagement<T:Config> {
        fn deposit(owner: T::AccountId, amount: u32) -> DispatchResult;
        // fn lock(owner: T::AccountId, amount: TokenCBalanceOf<T>) -> DispatchResult;
        // fn burn(owner: T::AccountId, amount: TokenCBalanceOf<T>) -> DispatchResult;
    }

    pub trait TokenBManagement<T:Config> {
        fn withdraw(owner: T::AccountId, amount: u32) -> DispatchResult;
        fn deposit(owner: T::AccountId, amount: u32) -> DispatchResult;
    }



    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_transaction_payment::Config {
        /// Because this pallet emits events, it depends on the runtime's definition of an event.
        type RuntimeEvent: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeEvent>;

        type TokenA : Currency<Self::AccountId>;
        type TokenB : Currency<Self::AccountId>;
        type TokenC : Currency<Self::AccountId>;

        type TokenAManagement: TokenAManagement<Self>;
        type TokenBManagement: TokenBManagement<Self>;
        type TokenCManagement: TokenCManagement<Self>;
    
        
    }
}
```

My code is a mess. Could you please give me some idea to implement them more efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

There exists `pallet-assets` to manage an arbitrary number of different distinct assets.
Alternatively there also is `pallet-nfts` for non-fungible assets.

Assets are addressed via an `ID` which makes it possible to easily write generic functions that operate on any asset. Additionally to this there is `pallet-asset-conversion` which is a Uniswap-like pallet for converting assets.